# Online index rebuild higher fragmentation on intermediate level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, index-maintenance, enterprise-edition

I need to rebuild some big indexes and I'm doing some tests with the various options (sort_in_tempdb, maxdop, online) of the `ALTER INDEX` statement on an test index with 4 levels and 800000 pages on leaf level.
I noticed when I'm running the statement with `Online=on` the intermediate pages (level 1) of my index are higher fragmented as before (89% in stead of 3%).

The intermediate pages only get defragmented when I'm setting `MAXDOP=1`.
With the options `SORT_IN_TEMBP=ON,ONLINE=OFF` the level 2 fragmentation jumps from 0 to 100.

This are the statements that caused an increase of fragmentation on level 1:

```
ALTER INDEX pk_test ON dbo.test REBUILD WITH (sort_in_tempdb=off,online=on,maxdop=1)
ALTER INDEX pk_test ON dbo.test REBUILD WITH (sort_in_tempdb=off,online=on)
ALTER INDEX pk_test ON dbo.test REBUILD WITH (sort_in_tempdb=on,online=on)
```

This statement caused the fragmentation on level 2 go from 0 to 100 but level 1 stays the same:

```
ALTER INDEX pk_test ON dbo.test REBUILD WITH (sort_in_tempdb=on,online=off)
```

Is fragmentation on intermediate pages something to worry about and what is causing the increase in fragmentation?

Comment: How many pages in level 1 / level 2? Is this fragmentation actually causing any performance issues? How did you correlate any performance issues with the fragmentation?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I did not have any performance issues in this test.
On level 1 I have 1500 pages and level 2 has only 2 pages.
I was wondering if this could cause performance issues on a production db

Comment: What fill factor are you using?

Comment: @MelvinLusk I use a fillfactor of 100%

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER INDEX pk_test ON dbo.test REBUILD WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON,  
    ONLINE = ON, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90, 
    OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = ON)
```

This way you will have a `FILLFACTOR` of 90% and you would probably avoid to have the table fragmentation to spike up again.

Keep in mind that your table size will increase of 10%